# Server on load after uploading big file

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

i have a problem on my server 
the server goes on load after uploading files big than 200MB
my server carateristique

```
Total processors: 12
Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz
Speed
3192.129 MHz

RAM : 64GB
Space : 4TB
```

after uploading files the server must convert files to other qualities 
i use ffmpeg tool to do it 
here take a look at this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZPS7.png

Comment: This seems normal to me. Transcoding video takes a lot of CPU. What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: just it's take 1 CPU per convert is ther any method to reduce it ?

Comment: You may be able to adjust the ffmpeg settings a bit to use less CPU. But I doubt this is what you want to do.  You probably want to use MORE CPU to produce smaller files so you save on the bandwidth wen serving them back.  Most products of this type use many transcoding boxes, or VMs. Uploads insert them into a queue and worker boxes pick them up when they have free cycles.